# Using JAXB but not getting the values

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to use the below code but I am not getting the values.

```
main
{
String example="<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><SOAP:Body><ns0:findCustomerResponse xmlns:ns0=\"http://service.jaxws.blog/\"><return id=\"123\"><firstName>Jane</firstName><lastName>Doe</lastName></return></ns0:findCustomerResponse></SOAP:Body></SOAP:Envelope>";
ByteArrayInputStream bas=new ByteArrayInputStream(example.getBytes());
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null,
                bas);
        JAXBElement<Customer> jb = unmarshaller.unmarshal(message.getSOAPBody(), Customer.class);

        Customer customer = jb.getValue();
        System.out.println(customer.id);
        System.out.println(customer.firstName);
        System.out.println(customer.lastName);
      }

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

    @XmlAttribute
    int id;

    String firstName;

    String lastName;

}
```

Please suggest why I am not getting values

Comment: U need to define getter and setter method for all variables inside JAXB class. Also need to define @XmlElement for firstName and lastName.

Comment: @additionster No you don't. The `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` annotation means that all fields are implicitly `@XmlElement`, unless otherwise annotated, and that JAXB will read/write field values directly, without use of getters and setters.

Comment: Why would you expect the `<SOAP:Body>` element to match your `Customer` class? The `id` attribute is on the `<return>` element, that is nested two deep, with a `<ns0:findCustomerResponse>` element in-between.

Comment: @Andreas but its fine to remove return tag but I am not getting any values where the output is  0,null,null but the expected is 123,Jane,Doe. Is there any changes required to get the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andreas said, the Customer is nested two deep in the SOAP body, so if you would like to get it then you can use the following, but I would say it's not so elegant:

```
JAXBElement<Customer> jb = unmarshaller.unmarshal(message.getSOAPBody().getFirstChild().getFirstChild(), Customer.class);
```

Comment: But in that case only 123 is coming but others are coming as null

Comment: Strange, I've just tried and it works on my side. Have you tried it with the same snippet you provided?

Comment: I have set package-info in the package and so there is a problem and get the value in seperate package.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just made a small change :

Replaced

JAXBElement jb = unmarshaller.unmarshal(message.getSOAPBody(), Customer.class);

with

JAXBElement jb = unmarshaller.unmarshal(message.getSOAPBody().getFirstChild().getFirstChild(), Customer.class);

And I got the answer

```
System.out.println(customer.id); // printed 123
System.out.println(customer.firstName); // printed Jane
System.out.println(customer.lastName); // printed Doe
```